# Collapse scroll для recycleview

Tags: android

Привет, всем, хотелось бы узнать, как реализовать вот такой скролл https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6k6l2ctmOw, есть подозрение, что можно использовать CoordinatorLayout.Behavior, но пока слабо представляю это.

Comment: Там же есть ссылка на гитхаб. Может, найдёте информацию там https://github.com/KlassenKonstantin/CollapseOnScroll/blob/master/library/src/main/java/de/klassen/konstantin/collapseonscroll/library/CollapseOnScrollView.java. В коде ListView используется, можно, значит, как-то приспособить к RecyclerView.

Comment: Да, видел, к сожалению recyclewView не приспособить.

Answer (score 1):

Подобрал неверный видео пример. Нашел, что мне требовалось - [Sticky Header](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/d959434f532d9983c25ba6a84aacf9edfa62677b/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f78736d314930462e676966)